# Tracking changes in SQL Server Memory optimized tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

We have a trigger based change-tracking setup in traditional (disk-based) tables in SQL Server 2014 where following changes to the main table are tracked in a separate audit table:

oldvalue, newvalue, changedbyuser, timestamp

We are evaluating migration to memory optimized tables. [Triggers are not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246937.aspx) in memory optimized tables. Therefore our trigger based approach for the traditional tables will no longer work.

[Service brokers provide asynchronous mechanisms](https://ajitananthram.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/auditing-external-activator/) to approach this problem, however, I am stuck on how to notify the service broker of table changes. I am exploring implementing thing using Query notification. A notifier will listen for changes on the tables and will notify service broker if/when there are changes.

I would like to know the community's thoughts on this.